# Safari view controller or WKWebKit

Tags: ios, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I would like to create an iOS app that accesses a Webpage that uses java script. The webpage has 3 login parameters, User ID, Password and Access code. Safari and Safari view controller will save the user ID and password but not the Access Code. 
I would like to be able to have the user enter their User ID, Password and Access code into 3 textfields and pass that data to the url and save that data in the app.
The goal of the app is to be able to login to the url when the app is launched without having to enter their credentials every time. The user's login credentials are only saved to the device in the app.
Which would be better, Safari view controller or WKWebview?

thanks,
John

Comment: Safari view controller is new in iOS9.And as I know, you can't get any info from it.

Comment: Same here, Im working on an app with the same functionality and Im trapped on making it pass the live session from the WKWebView to Safari. I heard about SFSafari but its documentation shows that its really fresh and needs more time to develop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think safariViewController is what you want.
You can store data as cookies.

[Check this out](https://github.com/mackuba/SafariAutoLoginTest).